# api.createType does not work?

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-types, typescript, types

I would like to create a type called **`XcmVersionedMultiLocation`**. It can be imported using the following code:

```
import { XcmVersionedMultiLocation } from "@polkadot/types/lookup";
```

To create an instance of this type, you can use the following code:

```
const loc = api.createType("XcmVersionedMultiLocation", {
  isV3: true,
  type: "V3",
  asV3: {
    parents: 1,
    interior: {
      isX2: true,
      asX2: [
        { isParachain: true, asParachain: 2100 },
        {
          isAccountId32: true,
          asAccountId32: {
            id: api.createType("AccountId32", address).toHex()
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

However, the **loc** variable here still has the type `Codec`. I am not sure why this is happening. Is there something else we need to do in order to get the correct type for `XcmVersionedMultiLocation`?

Let's consider an example:

```
const account = api.createType("AccountId32", address)
```

This correctly assigns the type "AccountId32" to the account variable.

Similarly, for the following code:

```
const loc = api.createType(
"MultiLocation",
{
    parents: "0",
    interior: {
        x1: { generalKey: "0x0001" }
    }
}
```

);

The loc variable correctly has the type `MultiLocation`.

I'm not sure why it's not working for `XcmVersionedMultiLocation`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XcmVersionedMultiLocation` type-example you shared can be created as follows :

```typescript
 const loc =  api.createType("XcmVersionedMultiLocation", {
                V3: {
                    parents: "1",
                    interior: {
                        X2: [
                         { parachain: "2100"},
                         { AccountId32: { id: address } }
                        ],
                    },
                },
            });
```

A complete example/code snippet would be something like the following (using a random account) :

```typescript
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');

async function main() {
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

    const xcmVersionedMultiLocation = {
        V3: {
          parents: "1",
          interior: {
            X2: [ 
                { parachain: "2100"},
                { AccountId32: 
                    {
                      id: "0x0987654309876543098765430987654309876543098765430987654309876543"        
                    }
                 } 
                ]
          },
        },
      };
    
    const loc = api.createType(
    "XcmVersionedMultiLocation",
    xcmVersionedMultiLocation
    );

    console.log(loc.toHex());  
}

main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

For the `id` make sure to use the public key. If you have the address in another format you can use the [subscan tool](https://polkadot.subscan.io/tools/format_transform) or [sidecar's convert endpoint](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/) to change it.

Regarding your question on why the `loc` variable might still have the type `Codec`, there is a similar question [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4826) and a possible explanation can be found here : [Since upgrading to the 7.x series, TypeScript augmentation is missing](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ/#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing).